# How to get covariate data from a geographic raster for `ppm`?

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, spatstat

I want to fit a Poisson point-process model with `spatstat::ppm` and I'm unsure what is the best way to feed covariate data to the function. I understand that `spatstat` expects planar coordinates, so I have transformed my point location data to a planar crs before creating a `ppp` point pattern object. The covariate data are in a raster stack with unprojected geographic coordinates and I understand that [projecting rasters is generally ill-advised](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338522/to-project-or-not-to-project-extracting-raster-values-with-r). I extracted covariate values for the point locations from the raster using the points' original geographic coordinates and `raster::extract`. So far so good. The issue is ...

> it is not sufficient to have observed the covariate only at the points
>   of the data point pattern; the covariate must also have been observed
>   at other locations in the window. -`ppm` helpfile

I appear to have two options for providing the covariate data to the `data` argument.

1. A pixel image; seems ill-advised because of raster projection issues.
2. A list of functions (one per covariate) that can be evaluated at any location (x,y) to obtain corresponding covariate values. This seems like the way to go, but my attempt at writing such a function turns out to be ridiculously slow. It calls `raster::extract` for each coordinate pair after transforming the coordinates to the raster's crs. While `raster::extract` is reasonably fast when given a large number of points, there appears to be a substantial overhead for each call. According to `microbenchmark`, the coordinate transformation takes about 4ms and the extraction takes about 582ms for a single covariate, or about 4 seconds for each point to get all 7 covariates. I don't know how many times `ppm` will want to call this, but if it's even once per point in the pattern, it'll take too long.

Is there some way I can find out what is the complete set of points that `ppm` will query for covariate data so that I can extract those beforehand with a single call?

It seems like my use case (covariates in a geographic raster) should be pretty common, so I'm guessing there's an established way to do this right. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a well written question clearly identifying you need. It would have been even better with a simple reproducible example using e.g. built-in data from `raster` and `spatstat` or artificially generated data. In lack of the reproducible example my answer will not contain any code but outline what you could do.

First step in `ppm` is to make a quadrature scheme or class `quad` or `logiquad` depending on which maximum likelihood approximation is used in `ppm`. These can be generated directly by the user via `quadscheme` or `quadscheme.logi`. The quadrature scheme contains all the points where `ppm` will evaluate the covariates. You can extract the coordinates of the quadrature scheme using the function `coords`. If you construct a `data.frame` with all covariates evaluated at these points you can supply that as the `data` argument to `ppm` while the quadrature scheme is the first argument. To understand things better try to read the Details section of `help(ppm.quad)`.

Another approach which may give you the optimal use of your data is to extract the grid points of you current raster stack together with all the covariate values and project this point data. Then convert it to a simple `data.frame` with columns `x`, `y`, `covar1`, `covar2`, etc. Then you can use `x` and `y` together with your point observations of interest to create a quadrature scheme manually and the remaining columns can be supplied as `data` to `ppm`.

It would be interesting to compare the results from both these approaches as well as the results from just projecting the raster stack and converting it to a list of `im` objects.